# Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat7

I have configured SSL on my tomcat. I referred to the steps from the following site to configure SSL:

```
 http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_To_Configure_SSL_For_Windows
```

I am using Win32 OpenSSL v0.9.8x Light installer and tomcat 7.0.22. But when I access  https://server.ensarm.com:8843/ it gives the following error:

```
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

I don't understand what could be the problem. :(

Answer (score 5):

Check your Apache error log, see if it has a message similar to:

> You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!

This may indicate you have configured Apache to listen on port 443 while the SSLEngine is not on.

In *httpd.conf* only set ONE listen directive:

> Listen *:80

Later in *httpd.conf* you should have something that looks like:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
Include conf/httpd-ssl.conf
</IfModule>
```

In *httpd-ssl.conf* (or equivalent config file) make sure you have enabled the SSLEngine prior to the Listen directive:

```
SSLEngine on
listen *:443
```

Restart Apache and you should be good to go.